# How to Control LED with NRF24l01 And arduino

Tags: arduino, wifi

I have a nrf24l01+PA+LNA .also i have arduino mega and nano boards. I try some arduino projects with it . but i cannot found a project which is working.Also i could not understand my nrf circuit is working.
Can anyone please give me a arduino code?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service.

Comment: A little search before asking here would give you what you want. And the nrf24l01 is NOT wifi chip, It's use a 2.4GHz frequency but not the same way wifi use.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to check the baud rate of your NRF24L01 and arduino are they both same? to check your arduino and nrf ckt perform this test :

Write Operation
1st send Read signal , register address of nrf ,  and then the value you have to write.Write operation will be done through SPI port of arduino.

Read Operation
1st send Write Signal , register address of nrf then wait for arduino to output the register value.

If written and read values are same then congratulations you have configured them both correctly and your circuit is working.

You can also look at : 
https://arduino-info.wikispaces.com/Nrf24L01-2.4GHz-HowTo